# Final Clarification About Image and Icon Names and Icon Sizes For iOS Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, icons

I'm hopefully about to upload my first app to Apple tonight for release and wanted to just ask for a small bit of clarification on a few items.

I've seen this Apple site (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) talking about icons names and that's all well and good.

My questions are:

1) do I have to Supply an iPad Icon even though I want my app to be iPhone only?

2) How do I ensure my app is iPhone only (I think I created universal at the start but don't want the iPad version there, so users won't be able to download it onto their iPads)?

3) The launch images I can see requires a specific naming convention, like Default–568h@2x.png for the iPhone 5 - again, do I have to supply iPad launch images?

4) I have custom navigation bars, tab bars and backgrounds within my app - do those have to have specific naming conventions?

5) I have a screen of tutorials at the start - does that have to have a specific naming convention?

6) I have a few images which aren't being used in the app right now - should I get rid of them?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You do not have to supply an iPad image.
2. In XCode, click your project name in the project navigator (left pane) Under the general tab, under deployment info, you can select iPhone from the drop down menu.
3. Again, I don't think so. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.
4. If you want to get rid of the images you may, but as long as you aren't seeing performance issues it probably isn't necessary.

Comment: I can confirm on point 3. I would add that it is worth adding iPad icons in, because otherwise the app icon may seem a little stretched on the iPad home screen. Secondly, even if you are only targeting iPhone iOS 7+ it is worth having non-retina assets because the iPad 2 and iPad mini 1 (both non-retina) will still try to use these.

Comment: Thank you Chris and Thomas - very much appreciated and great answers and recommendations

Comment: Hi Guys - sorry - do I have to supply a launch image for the iPad? (iPhone only app).. and if so or if recommended, should I use the "Default@2x.png" that I'm currently using for iPhone 4S?

and do I have to add the iTunesArtwork to the plist as well?